# Как перевести String в шестнадцатеричную систему счисления и обратно

Tags: java, android

Как перевести String в  шестнадцатеричную систему счисления и обратно.

```
String url="1egwMxTKMsXQzs-SYdrGB-F8m5h0AEMQg";
```

Comment: а что вы хотите получить в результате для этой строки?

Comment: Как то максимально  ее сделать непонятной . Можно не в 16 .Чтобы сходу не было понятно ссылку

Comment: просто непонятно что вы подразумеваете под `шестнадцатеричной системой счисления`, система счисления - это способ записи именно _чисел_. Возможно вы хотите зашифровать строку?

Comment: @timbars в 16-тиричной системе можно отобразить не только числа :)

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar это понятно, но в любом случае надо как-то предварительно получать числа, я на это намекал

Answer (score 4):

Есть такой пакетик `DatatypeConverter`, в котором если на вход подать массив байтов, то можно получить все что угодно. Вопрос только в том, как получить из строки байты. По хорошему метод `String.getBytes()` делает это, но проблема в том, что при этом используется текущая локаль/кодировка. Чтобы не зависеть от локали, надо явно указывать кодировку, примерно так.

```
String hex=DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Для шифрования базы можно использовать обычный xor:

```
private const val SECRET = "you key"

object Base64Xor {
    fun encode(s: String, key: String = SECRET): String {
        return Base64.encodeBase64ToString(xorWithKey(s.toByteArray(), key.toByteArray()))
    }

    fun decode(s: String, key: String = SECRET): String {
        return String(xorWithKey(Base64.decodeBase64ToByteArray(s), key.toByteArray()))
    }

    private fun xorWithKey(a: ByteArray, key: ByteArray): ByteArray {
        val out = ByteArray(a.size)
        for (i in a.indices) {
            out[i] = (a[i] xor key[i % key.size]) as Byte
        }
        return out
    }
}
```

*В области компьютерных наук Base64 представляет собой группу схем кодирования двоичного текста в текст, которые представляют двоичные данные в строковом формате ASCII, переводя их в представление radix-64. Термин Base64 происходит от конкретной кодировки передачи содержимого MIME. Каждая цифра Base64 представляет ровно 6 бит данных. Таким образом, три 8-битных байта (то есть всего 24 бита) могут быть представлены четырьмя 6-битными цифрами Base64.* (ист. Википедия)

```
object Base64 {
    fun encodeBase64ToString(input: String): String = String(input.toByteArray().encodeBase64())
    fun encodeBase64ToByteArray(input: String): ByteArray = input.toByteArray().encodeBase64()
    fun encodeBase64ToString(input: ByteArray): String = String(input.encodeBase64())

    fun decodeBase64(input: String): String = String(input.toByteArray().decodeBase64())
    fun decodeBase64ToByteArray(input: String): ByteArray = input.toByteArray().decodeBase64()
    fun decodeBase64ToString(input: ByteArray): String = String(input.decodeBase64())

    fun ByteArray.encodeBase64(): ByteArray {
        val table = (CharRange('A', 'Z') + CharRange('a', 'z') + CharRange('0', '9') + '+' + '/' + '=').toCharArray()
        val output = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        var padding = 0
        var position = 0
        while (position < this.size) {
            var b = this[position].toInt() and 0xFF shl 16 and 0xFFFFFF
            if (position + 1 < this.size) b = b or (this[position + 1].toInt() and 0xFF shl 8) else padding++
            if (position + 2 < this.size) b = b or (this[position + 2].toInt() and 0xFF) else padding++
            for (i in 0 until 4 - padding) {
                val c = b and 0xFC0000 shr 18
                output.write(table[c].toInt())
                b = b shl 6
            }
            position += 3
        }
        for (i in 0 until padding) {
            output.write('='.toInt())
        }
        return output.toByteArray()
    }

    fun ByteArray.decodeBase64(): ByteArray {
        val table = intArrayOf(-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
            -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 62, -1, -1, -1, 63, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, -1, -1, -1,
            -1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
            -1, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
            -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
            -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
            -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
            -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)

        val output = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        var position = 0
        while (position < this.size) {
            var b: Int
            if (table[this[position].toInt()] != -1) {
                b = table[this[position].toInt()] and 0xFF shl 18
            } else {
                position++
                continue
            }
            var count = 0
            if (position + 1 < this.size && table[this[position + 1].toInt()] != -1) {
                b = b or (table[this[position + 1].toInt()] and 0xFF shl 12)
                count++
            }
            if (position + 2 < this.size && table[this[position + 2].toInt()] != -1) {
                b = b or (table[this[position + 2].toInt()] and 0xFF shl 6)
                count++
            }
            if (position + 3 < this.size && table[this[position + 3].toInt()] != -1) {
                b = b or (table[this[position + 3].toInt()] and 0xFF)
                count++
            }
            while (count > 0) {
                val c = b and 0xFF0000 shr 16
                output.write(c.toChar().toInt())
                b = b shl 8
                count--
            }
            position += 4
        }
        return output.toByteArray()
    }
}
```

В сумме вы получаете надежные механизм шифровки своих данных.

Comment: Не надо путать шифрование с кодированием. Base64 - это никакое не шифрование, а просто способ отобразить 8 битов с помощью 6 битов.

Comment: @BarmaleyRedStar не сразу понял замечание, но описку исправил